# Strange MX problem / issue with subdomains

Tags: dns

I am a bit confused with regards to MX and wildcard-A-entries in a dns zone.

Imagine a zone foobar.com with these dns settings (NS set is there, leaving out)

```
foobar.com IN A 1.2.3.4
*.foobar.com IN A 1.2.3.4

foobar.com IN MX 10 mail.otherhost.com
```

When sending mail to something@foobar.com this goes to mail.otherhost.com. All right.

When sending mail to something@some-subdomain.foobar.com this goes to 1.2.3.4.

As I understand this is correct with https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt there "2.7 Wildcard records" and the example (its vice versa, but anyway).

My question now is: How do MTAs like Postfix "strip" the subdomain part from the host part when getting ("resolving") the MX host?

My problem of understanding is: If the top level domain is .com, this is simple. Host ist the part before .com. But there are many top level domains with sub-top-level, e.g. .co.at (Austria).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *How do MTAs like Postfix "strip" the subdomain part from the host part when getting ("resolving") the MX host?*

They don't. The MX record for an address is requested. If one doesn't exist the A record is used to determine the target IP address.

In your example you have `something@some-subdomain.foobar.com`, where the subdomain for delivery is `some-subdomain.foobar.com`. The sending MTA requests an MX for this address. In your example there isn't one so the A record is requested. There isn't one but the wildcard `*.foobar.com` is matched, which returns an address of `1.2.3.4`. This is the address to which delivery is attempted.

CNAME records make this a little more complicated, but not much: if there is a CNAME then it is resolved before anything else. (This is why you cannot have a CNAME and an MX for the same domain entry.)

Comment: Thank you so much!